# Deriving the mean from a raw and standardized score

Tags: mean, standardization

My son has received 52 marks in a test.
This has been standardized, using a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15, as 102.27

What is the mean mark, and how many marks would he have needed to get to achieve a standardized score of 111?

Comment: Is this question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 1):

We know that a score of $52$ is $\frac{2.27}{15}$ of a standard deviation (on the marks) above the mean (of the raw marks). That is,
$$
52 = \mu + \frac{2.27}{15} \sigma
.$$
Unfortunately, this is a linear system with only one equation and two unknowns. You'd need another raw-standardized pair, or separate knowledge of either $\mu$ or $\sigma$, to find either $\mu$ or $\mu + \frac{11}{15}\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed Dougal. If I can establish either of these variables I will get back to you.